# VBA to select all and deselect 0 & blank in one field on pivot tables across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

This is a re-post of my problem here because I dun goofed and thought I solved it when my VBA didn't work.

Essentially what I want the VBA to do is go to the pivot tables across multiple sheets, in the quantity field I want it to select all and then deselect 0 and blank. This will select new data in the filter when I have refreshed it with the new input data for the report I do on a weekly basis. The code is as below

```
 Sub Main()

    With ThisWorkbook
        FilterOutZeroAndBlanks .Worksheets("Cairns Table").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
        FilterOutZeroAndBlanks .Worksheets("Other Table").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    End With

End Sub

Public Sub FilterOutZeroAndBlanks(pvt As PivotTable)

    Dim pvtField As PivotField
    Set pvtField = pvt.PivotFields("Quantity")
    
    Dim item As PivotItem
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim targetCounter As Long
    
    With pvtField
        For Each item In .PivotItems
            If item.Visible Then counter = counter + 1
        Next item
        
        If .PivotItems("0").Visible And .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible Then
            targetCounter = 2
        ElseIf .PivotItems("0").Visible Or .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible Then
            targetCounter = 1
        End If
        
        If Not targetCounter = counter Then
            .PivotItems("0").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Public Sub FilterOutZeroAndBlanks(pvt As PivotTable)

    With pvt.PivotFields("Quantity")
        .ShowAllItems = True 'unhide all
        .PivotItems("0").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: It did not work unfortunately, im stuck trying to figure this one out. below is the complete module:

Sub Main()

    With ThisWorkbook
        FilterOutZeroAndBlanks .Worksheets("Summary Table").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
        FilterOutZeroAndBlanks .Worksheets("Cairns Table").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    End With

End Sub

Public Sub FilterOutZeroAndBlanks(pvt As PivotTable)

    With pvt.PivotFields("Quantity")
        .ShowAllItems = True 'unhide all
        .PivotItems("0").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    
End Sub

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive about *how* it didn't work?  Did you get an error?  If you need to post code then please edit it into your question.